# Can Spring 3 supports WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Is it possible to use [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) in `spring 3`?

As mentioned on [wikipedia of Spring Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) `Spring 3` was released in 2009 and web socket was introduced in 2011.

I know that `Spring 4` has support for `websocket` but our legacy application uses only `spring 3`.

Is it possible to use web socket in spring 3 and how can do it?

Comment: 2011, not 2001. There's no support in the framework itself in version 3.

Comment: right, updated the question.